# Erro ao criar procedure no oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

Ao declarar o nome de uma procedure no sqldevelope

recebo essa mensagem

```
Erro: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

Exemplo de nomenclatura:

```
PRC_IMVW_TISS_VERIFICA_ELEGIBILIDADE


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_IMVW_TISS_VERIFICA_ELEGIBILIDADE AS    
BEGIN 

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World!');     

END PRC_IMVW_TISS_VERIFICA_ELEGIBILIDADE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você encontrar um erro ORA-00972, a seguinte mensagem de erro aparecerá:

> ORA-00972: identifier is too long.

Tradução:

> ORA-00972: o identificador é muito longo

Procurando encontrei a referencia sobre esse erro:

> Cause: The name of a schema object exceeds 30 characters. 
>        Schema objects are tables, clusters, views, indexes, synonyms, tablespaces, and usernames.

Tradução

> Você tentou fazer referência a uma tabela, cluster, exibição, índice,
>   sinônimo, tablespace ou nome de usuário com um valor superior a 30
>   caracteres.

Solução:

> Action: Shorten the name to 30 characters or less.

Tradução

> Os nomes para tabelas, clusters, visualizações, índices, sinônimos,
>   espaços de tabela e nomes de usuários devem ter 30 caracteres ou
>   menos. Você deve encurtar o nome para não mais de 30 caracteres para
>   esses objetos.

O nome da sua **procedure** possui 36 caracteres, remova 6 caracteres que o erro não irá mais ocorrer.

Fonte: http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00972_identifier_is_too_long.htm